# how can I get rid of old versions of software on lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

Without knowing whether they are there or not. I notice I have a java policy tools 6 and 7 which means that the old one didn't go.

I would like to clean up the computer by getting rid of old software/conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. But you may want to verify. In the terminal, type in:

```
locate policytool
```

Do you get java-6-openjdk files AND java-7-openjdk files? If so, simply uninstall the openjdk6 files.

Open synaptic (Menu -> System Tools -> Synaptic Package Manager) and search for openjdk.

[image: Synaptic]

Right click the openjdk-6 files, and remove.

[image: Remove]

Comment: Thanks I'm ok with that example specifically. I was just wondering if there was a way to locate sneakier examples without first knowing they are there.